# quit link of categories on active page. (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, categories

I'm a new at the forum & need help.

Wordpress have a wp_list_categories, that display all categories existing in your page. And every category with respective link. Example.

(Categories link)

Animales
Travels
Foods
Music.

When I click on "Animals" go in the "animals" page, or click on "Travels" it's same. This not problem. But my situation is that, when I click on any category so:

1- The link of the page that where I am, is removed. The link, but the category no. I mean, if I click on "Travels" then:

Animals (Is link)
Travels (Is only text)
Food (Is link)
Music (Is link)

or:

2- If you can not remove the link, at least something that's indicate that I am in that category. (Link another color or something like that).

Either options are good.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to hide the current category is to exclude it from `wp_list_categories` each time using the current category ID, for example:

```
<?php 
     // Get the current category
     $currentCategory = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
     // Then get the ID
     $currentCategoryID = $currentCategory->cat_ID;
     // Then exclude the ID
     wp_list_categories('exclude=' . $currentCategoryID ); 
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this as the answer when you can :)